# Twitter Bootstrap : Table overflowing a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The following is my code. I'm creating a 12-row span in a container. I have a table inside this row, whose content is changing dynamically. However, I find that my content overflows the row vertically

```
<div class="container-fluid">       
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <pre>
            <table border="1" align="right" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="10">
            <tr>
            <td id="three"><div id="name"></div></td>
            <td id="one"><div id="something"></div></td>
        <td id="two"></div></td>            
        </tr>
        </table>
        </pre>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

A screenshot of what is happening :

[image]

Is there a way to change the height of the row-fluid?

Comment: add a property `clear: both` to the div wrapping the table. There must be a float property on it which is messing things up